# Find complex residue and Laurent series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus, laurent-series

$$ w = \sin(z) * \sin(\frac{1}{\:z}) $$

special point is $$ z_0 = 0 $$
$$ \lim _{z\to 0}\left(\sin\left(z\right)\cdot \:\sin\:\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right) $$ isn't exist, next I have to decompose both functions in Laurent series.
$$\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5\text{}}{5!}-... $$
$$ \sin\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z^33!}+\frac{1}{z^55!} $$
after, multiplication series I have to find $$ c^{-1} $$ addend in Laurent series, and coefficients with it will be residue?
but 
$$ 1+\frac{1}{3!\cdot 3!}+\frac{1}{5!\cdot 5!} $$

Comment: $\LaTeX$ advice: use \sin for sine function.

Comment: thanks for hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The residue is $0$ since two odd terms $z^m$ and $z^{-k}$ will always make an even term when multiplied: $z^mz^{-k} = z^{m-k}$.

Comment: Thanks, 
Should I find residue at infinity?

Comment: *Must I have to find?

Comment: @DmitrySokolov Residue at infinity is the residue of $-\frac{1}{z^2} f(\frac{1}{z})$ at $0$. Now, we have $f(\frac{1}{z}) = f(z)$ and the even term $\frac{1}{z^2}$ won't change the parity of a term it multiplies, so again we have zero residue at infinity.

Comment: I mean:Is Infinity isolated singular point?

Comment: @DmitrySokolov Yes it is. Notice also that both $0$ and infinity are essential singularities.

Comment: But why Limit at infinity is 0?

Comment: The function doesn't have a limit neither at infinity nor at zero. They are essential singularities.

Comment: https://bit.ly/2GppIfG
WolframAlpha said that limit is zero

Comment: @DmitrySokolov Oh, right and it also says that the limit is zero when approaching $0$. But if you do the product of Laurent series there are terms on both sides. Maybe the other $\sin$ goes to zero and makes it zero?

Comment: So they wouldn't be singularities after all but removable ones... (?)

Comment: Ok, I'm rather puzzled about this. For example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195636/laurent-series-for-sin-z-sin1-z the Laurent series is calculated and clearly there are terms infinitely on in both directions. If the limit were $0$, there wouldn't be any negative exponent terms. And actually another reason to see why both the limits at infinity and at zero can't be $0$ is that the function would be bounded and analytic in the entire complex plane which would mean it is constant.

Comment: I think WolframAlpha goes awry here. As you can see, when it does the series expansion, it doesn't touch the other factor ($\sin(z)$) at all but only does it for $\sin(\frac{1}{z})$.